# Docker cronjob rights not correct if not running under root

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an docker container running with Apache. This was started with docker-compose under the root user. In this container de webserver runs under the default user www-data. Via conjob I trigger the php script for uploading images. This works fine if the cronjob runs under root. But I want to have the conjob running under www-data so the uploaded files have the same owner as files that are uploaded directly via apache.

I use the following cronjob (this works):

```
*/1 * * * * docker exec apache_1 php /var/www/import
```

But when I change the cronjob user to www-data (does not trigger anymore):

```
*/1 * * * * www-data docker exec apache_1 php /var/www/import
```

With the last cronjob the php script inside the container is not triggered anymore. I believe it has to do with permission settings?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `import` command to be executed by www-data inside the container, specify it to docker:

```
*/1 * * * * docker exec --user www-data apache_1 php /var/www/import
```

With what you've tried, the user www-data has not permissions to run docker commands. And, you have not such option to specify the username in `crontab -e` (what you tried to do should be in /etc/crontab, or use su/sudo).

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to run the command as the user while signed into the root user account your command should be:

```
su www-data; docker exec apache_1 php /var/www/import
```

Otherwise you need to switch to the www-data user(sudo su www-data) and then edit the cron jobs for the user(crontab -e).  Each user has their own cronjobs.

Comment: sudo groupadd docker

Comment: The `php` will still be running as root as docker do it by default

Comment: I checked, but it is not working. Indeed they keep running under the root account. Any other solution possible?

Comment: try crontab -u www-data -e

Comment: also make sure when the cronjob starts that you run su www-data(which switches the logged in user from root to www-data).  It may need to be placed in a bash script that is ran by cron.